# Segmentation fault in QHash

Tags: qt, qhash

I got the following crash in `QHash`. I am unable to find any thing into. I am using Qtopia-Core-4.3.3 on Linux Machine.

The log is as follows:

> ASSERT: "*node == e || (*node)->next" in file
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/QtopiaCore-4.3.3-400wrl/include/QtCore/qhash.h,
>   line 824
>   Segmentation fault

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Actually,i do not know,from where this assert is being generated. It would be difficult to post the code,it is of 30,000 lines.

Comment: If you're using Windows and Visual Studio, run the application, break on assertion, then go to the last stack entry in you code.

Comment: Run under valgrind, and then post the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but based on the fact that `QHash` is a container, and it is referring to "node", I think the given assertion is caused by the program expecting that the node is either the end node (`e`), or has a next node.  So it appears something you are doing is messing up the entries in the hash.

To continue to speculate wildly, I have often seen some hard-to-diagnose errors when someone was iterating over a container, and sometimes removing things from the container while iterating.  I don't know if `QHash` handles this nicely or not.